# Keyup functions not working on Datatable search

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2ahtjx5/4/) for reference.

I am trying to have keypress events work on the search textbox of the Database. Issue is, it's not working. I can't track what's wrong?

The following code snippet seems not to be working.

```
if ($("#example_filter input").length > 0) {
    alert("search exists");
}
$("#example_filter input").on("keyup", function() {
    alert("hi");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first add `DataTable` and then bind the events. Because at the time when you bind the `keyup` event on `input`, the `input` was not present in the `DOM`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#example_filter input").length > 0) {
        alert("search exists");
    }
    $("#example").DataTable();

    $("#example_filter").on("keyup", 'input', function() {
        alert("hi");
    });
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/m2ahtjx5/5/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are creating your `dataTable` after assigning the `event`. So create table and then assign it!!

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/m2ahtjx5/6/)**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    if($("#example_filter input").length > 0)
    {
        alert("search exists");
    }

    $("#example").DataTable();
    $("#example_filter input").on("keyup",function(){
       alert("hi");    
    });
});
```

If you would have followed your way like creating `dataTable` later then you should have used `event delegation` as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/m2ahtjx5/9/)**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
    if($("#example_filter input").length > 0)
    {
        alert("search exists");
    }
    $(document).on("keyup",'#example_filter input',function(){
       alert("hi");    
    }); //event delegation
    $("#example").DataTable();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/m2ahtjx5/8/)**.

The input was created after the delegation was done. The following can be used for binding a function to element which was not on `DOM` on ready.

```
$(document).on("keyup", "#example_filter input", function () {
    alert("hi");
});
```